# SortableJS not dropping on dynamically created empty list

Tags: jquery-ui-sortable, sortablejs

I want to be able to dynamically add new lists / groups and be able to drag and drop between them. SortableJS only seems to want to drop into pre-existing containers.

This [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/torowebaja/edit?html,js,output) demonstrates what I'm trying to accomplish. Click 'Add Group', then try to drag an item into the new group.

Is there some setting I'm missing or some setup function on the dynamic list or make the existing ones aware of the new one? I tried `.sortable('refresh')` and `dropOnEmpty: true`(which should be the default anyway) with little luck.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector in addGroup() for the newly created div items-3 is wrong - it's missing the # to select by ID - so you are basically running with an empty selection therefore not initializing any new sortable.
Correct line:

```
$('#items-3').sortable(
```